# Div expand button for longer text but only one button

Tags: jquery

I'm using a couple of div's with the same classes.
Now when one of the div's contains text with over 150 characters it needs to get an expand button to expand the div.

So far the button is attached to the div when the text is over 150 characters. But, when I click the button, the div expands but also another div gets expanded and is buggy.

How can I fix this, so that only the div with the clicked button gets expanded?

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  var limit = 150;
  var i = $('.item .item-inner');
  $(i).each(function(){
    var text = $(this).find('.item-content').text();
    if (text.length > limit) {
      limit = text.length;
      item = this;
      $(item).append('<button class="item-extend">expand</button>');
    }
  });
  $('.item-extend').click(function () {
    $(item).animate({"height":"600px"}, 500);
  }, function () {
    $(item).animate({"height":"300px"}, 300);
  });
});
```

```css
.item {
  float:left;
  width:25%;
}
.item-inner {
  background: #ccc;
  padding:10px;
  margin:10px;
  height:200px;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.item-extend {
  position:absolute;
  bottom:10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item">
  <div class="item-inner">
    <p class="item-content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="item">
  <div class="item-inner">
    <p class="item-content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="item">
  <div class="item-inner">
    <p class="item-content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem ipsum dolor sit</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="item">
  <div class="item-inner">
    <p class="item-content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your `click` handler, `item` was the last `.item-inner` defined in the `.each()` loop... So the last column.

Using `$(this).parent(".item-inner")` will target the right column.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  var limit = 150;
  var i = $('.item .item-inner');
  $(i).each(function(){
    var text = $(this).find('.item-content').text();
    if (text.length > limit) {
      limit = text.length;
      item = this;
      $(item).append('<button class="item-extend">expand</button>');
    }
  });
  $('.item-extend').click(function () {
    $(this).parent(".item-inner").animate({"height":"600px"}, 500);
  }, function () {
    $(this).parent(".item-inner").animate({"height":"300px"}, 300);
  });
});
```

```css
.item {
  float:left;
  width:25%;
}
.item-inner {
  background: #ccc;
  padding:10px;
  margin:10px;
  height:200px;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.item-extend {
  position:absolute;
  bottom:10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item">
  <div class="item-inner">
    <p class="item-content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="item">
  <div class="item-inner">
    <p class="item-content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="item">
  <div class="item-inner">
    <p class="item-content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem ipsum dolor sit</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="item">
  <div class="item-inner">
    <p class="item-content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

you need to target the closest `.item-inner` for that you can use `$(this).closest('.item-inner')` in click handler of `.item-extend` something like this:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
 var limit = 150;
 var i = $('.item .item-inner');
 $(i).each(function(){
     var text = $(this).find('.item-content').text();
     if (text.length > limit) {
         limit = text.length;
         item = this;
     $(item).append('<button class="item-extend">expand</button>');
     }
 });
 $('.item-extend').click(function () {
  $(this).closest('.item-inner').animate({"height":"600px"}, 500);
  });
});
```

```css
.item {
float:left;
width:25%;
}
.item-inner {
background: #ccc;
padding:10px;
margin:10px;
height:200px;
overflow:hidden;
}
.item-extend {
  position:absolute;
  bottom:10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item">
  <div class="item-inner">
  <p class="item-content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="item">
  <div class="item-inner">
  <p class="item-content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="item">
  <div class="item-inner">
  <p class="item-content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem ipsum dolor sit</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="item">
  <div class="item-inner">
  <p class="item-content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you cannot use $(item) in the button click event. You need to select the button with $(this)  and then traverse to its parent .item-inner

Try this.

```
$(this).closest('.item-inner').animate({"height":"600px"}, 500);
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this? Just find the parent div for the button clicked and animate.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  var limit = 150;
  var i = $('.item .item-inner');
  $(i).each(function(){
    var text = $(this).find('.item-content').text();
    if (text.length > limit) {
      limit = text.length;
      item = this;
      $(item).append('<button class="item-extend">expand</button>');
    }
  });
  $('.item-extend').click(function () {
    $(this).parent('div').animate({"height":"600px"}, 500);
  }, function () {
    $(this).parent('div').animate({"height":"300px"}, 300);
  });
});
```

```css
.item {
  float:left;
  width:25%;
}
.item-inner {
  background: #ccc;
  padding:10px;
  margin:10px;
  height:200px;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.item-extend {
  position:absolute;
  bottom:10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item">
  <div class="item-inner">
    <p class="item-content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="item">
  <div class="item-inner">
    <p class="item-content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="item">
  <div class="item-inner">
    <p class="item-content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem ipsum dolor sit</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="item">
  <div class="item-inner">
    <p class="item-content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit </p>
  </div>
</div>
```